# Movies Data rest Api nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to fetch the Hollywood movies data. I have referred many APIs like IMDB, omdb, etc but all these APIs are taking a query string as a required parameter.

But i want some dummy data of movies without passing query string as a parameter with all details of movies like title, poster_image etc.

So please tell me something so that I can move further on this.

Comment: Calling IMDB API is simple as `GET http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[your key]&s=abc`, what's the reason for not passing the query string?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And note that asking us to recommend "other APIs" is off topic, too,

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, however, have you tried googling "imdb dataset"

Here is what i have found, you need to register on their site and download CSV. Which you can later import to your DB.

[IMDB Dataset - Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/orgesleka/imdbmovies#imdb.csv)